# In Azure API Management, skip the <backend> request if basic validation fails

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, is it possible to skip the **backend** call if some simple validation fails?  I require this because every call to the backend service in this case uses a portion the clients quota, and this is undesirable if we know that the request will fail.

Take the following example, where the URL template is `/MyOperation/{MyParameter}`:

- the **`<inbound>`** portion of the policy first checks whether or not `{MyParameter}` is numeric, and then rewrites the URI.
- the **`<outbound>`** portion of the policy checks whether or not `{MyParameter}` was valid, and if not instead returns some custom text to the client.

Here is the example policy -

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="isValidMyParameter" value="@{
            Match match = Regex.Match(context.Request.MatchedParameters["MyParameter"], "^[0-9]*$");
            return ( match.Value.ToString() != "" ) ? true : false;
        }" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/Path/To/Application/" + ""+context.Request.MatchedParameters["MyParameter"])" />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition=""@(!Convert.ToBoolean(context.Variables["isValidMyParameter"]))">
                <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>{ "statusCode": 400, "message": "Invalid 'MyParameter'." }</set-body>
            </when>
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

While the works, even if `{MyParameter}` is invalid (say the client has passed "asdf"), a request to the backend service is made. As explained above this is undesirable because it eats in to the clients quota.

I've considered using `<choose>` and checking the value of `isValidMyParameter`, but the trouble there is that a request to the backend service is still made, just without the rewritten URI.  This again eats in to the clients quota.

Is it at all possible to just skip the `<backend>` portion of the policy and go straight back to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move choose and add return-response policy within inbound body. This will result in immediate response to client skipping the backend request.

```
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="isValidMyParameter" value="@{
        Match match = Regex.Match(context.Request.MatchedParameters["MyParameter"], "^[0-9]*$");
        return ( match.Value.ToString() != "" ) ? true : false;
    }" />

    <choose>  
        <when condition="@(!Convert.ToBoolean(context.Variables["isValidMyParameter"]))">
            <return-response>  
               <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>{ "statusCode": 400, "message": "Invalid 'MyParameter'." }</set-body>
            </return-response>                
        </when>
    </choose> 

    <rewrite-uri template="@("/Path/To/Application/" + ""+context.Request.MatchedParameters["MyParameter"])" />
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into return-response policy. It would allow you to immediately stop request processing and return response to a client.

Comment: what we have xslt transforamtion in outbound policy , will it still work  fine ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi No, the outbound policy will not get executed. The `return-response` terminates the policy execution pipeline, i.e., no further policies will be executed. Instead, the response is returned immediately.

If you rely on that outbound policy you cannot use `return-response`.